# Pandas: How to edit values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I have a df with a column of values prefix: {H, HR, S, etc.}. I would like to edit the values such that it returns `h` for all `H, HR, HJ, HC` and `s` for all `S, SR, SJ SC`. The data is [here](https://github.com/108michael/ms_thesis/blob/master/mpl_data114.csv.zip)

```
    session prefix  number  disposition     catcode     bill
0   114     H   131     support     J6200   H131
1   114     H   138     oppose  L1100   H138
2   114     H   140     support     NaN     H140
3   114     H   140     oppose  J7500   H140
4   114     H   140     support     NaN     H140
```

I ran the following from MaxU:
    df.replace({'prefix': {r'^(H|HR|HC|HJ|)$': 'h', r'^(S|SR|SC|SJ|)$': 's'}}, regex=True, inplace=True)

and it works! Problem solved!

```
session     prefix  number  disposition     catcode
0   114     h   131     support     J6200
1   114     h   138     oppose  L1100
2   114     h   140     support     NaN
```

Comment: I couldn't find any `H*` and `S*` in your file. Do you want to replace all prefixes starting with `H` to `H`, and the same for all prefixes starting with `S` --> `S`?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for looking. I was thinking to learn from the pattern from the example. I have updated the question with your suggestion.

Comment: Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.replace({'prefix': {r'^(H|HR|H\*)$': 'h', r'^(S|SR|S\*)$': 's'}}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

if you want to have only the first letter of your prefix column:

```
df.prefix.str[0]
```

so to replace it with the first letter in lower case:

```
df.prefix = df['prefix'].str[0].str.lower()
```

Comment: @MichaelPerdue, please define `some cases`